# Deployment of web application in VS 2012 to my server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment

I have Web Application which I would like to deploy to my web server. I do not want to use Windows Azure, I have my own server. I even do not have my profile to publish to Azure. I believe it is OK to not have the profile and continue using VS2012. I would like have complied binary files and all my pages (master, aspx) together with my controls (ascx), js, css files and without code-behind files placed in my local folder. Then I plan to pack them and copy to my server through FTP. Sounds trivial. But...

When I hit right click over my Web Application project and then "Publish...", I have Publish Web window. The first step asks me if I want to publish to Windows Azure. In this case I have to provide my profile which I do not have. I do not need it. I just want to deploy to my local folder all except code-behind files. I cannot choose the next step which is "Connection". So I hit "Publish" button. And now, now I am stuck, because I have to provide my profile (see attached screenshot). Could you tell me how I can prepare my web application for deployment to my web server? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not planning on using Azure, simply ignore the statement at the top of that screen, it is only helpful if you are publishing to Azure.

To get past this step, click on the drop down and then click "New profile".
After that you will be taken through the rest of the wizard were you can setup your connection details etc.